# Nginx htpasswd getting 403 after successful login

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

I want to access the folder `/folder/subfolder/` in the webservers root (`/var/www/dl.somewebsite.com/files/`) with a password the rest should be public accessible. Using the script below I get a 403 Forbidden error when using the right credentials. What am I missing out here?

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name dl.somewebsite.com;

            access_log /var/www/nginx-logs/dl.somewebsite.com combined;

        root /var/www/dl.somewebsite.com/files/;

        location / {
            autoindex on;
        }

        location ^~ /folder/subfolder/ {
             auth_basic  "Restricted";
             auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/somefolder/dl.somewebsite.com/.htpasswd;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect instead of getting `403 Forbidden`?

Comment: The page that was restricted ;)

Comment: And what does the access / error log say, about the request?

Comment: How did you encode/encrypt the password? Or how exactly did you generate the .htpasswd file?

Comment: `htpasswd -c someusername` from apache2 utilities

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the `/etc/nginx/somefolder/dl.somewebsite.com/.htpasswd` that you configured is actually there.

If that doesn't solve, you can figure out the problem checking the `access.log` or `error.log`.
Use `docker logs -f CONTAINER`, or directly access the webserver via SSH and run `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` (exact location may differ).